# Split strings on commas, 'and's, 'or's

Tags: python, regex, string, tokenize

I would like to go from a naturally written string list to a python list.

Sample inputs:

```
s1 = 'make the cake, walk the dog, and pick-up poo.'
s2 = 'flour, egg-whites and sand.'
```

The output:

```
split1 = ['make the cake', 'walk the dog', 'pick-up poo']
split2 = ['flour', 'egg-whites', 'sand']
```

I want to split the strings on commas (and periods), 'and', and 'or', while removing the splits and empty strings. Because of the lack of standardization in using the oxford comma, I cannot just split on commas.

I tried the following:

```py
import re
[x.strip() for x in re.split('([A-Za-z -]+)', s1) if x not in ['', ',', '.']]
```

Which gives:

```
['make the cake', 'walk the dog', 'and pick-up poo']
```

Which is close. But for `s2` it gives:

```
['flour', 'egg-whites and sand']
```

I can do some post processing across elements to continually split elements by `(and|or)`, but I really would like to tokenize by the set of commas, and's, and or's.

I've tried some fancy regex splits to have a negative look ahead for something like `and`, but it doesn't want to split on that word.

```
[x.strip() for x in re.split('([A-Za-z -]+(?!and))', s2) if x not in ['', ',', '.']]
[x.strip() for x in re.split('([A-Za-z -]+(?!\band\b))', s2) if x not in ['', ',', '.']]
```

Which also gives

```
['flour', 'egg-whites and sand']
```

I realize there's a lot of edge cases but I feel like I'm close and just missing something small.

Comment: Instead of regex you could also consider replacing all target tokens with e.g. a comma, and then splitting based on the comma, discarding blanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
\s*(?:\b(?:and|or)\b|[,.])\s*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V9bDW0/1). Details:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:\b(?:and|or)\b|[,.])` - either a whole word `and` or `or`, or a comma/period
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mPQ9l2):

```py
import re
rx = re.compile(r"\s*(?:\b(?:and|or)\b|[,.])\s*")
strings = ["make the cake, walk the dog, and pick-up poo.", "flour, egg-whites and sand."]
for s in strings:
    print( list(filter(None, rx.split(s))) )
```

Note that a comma or period are often "excluded" when followed or enclosed with digits, you may consider replacing `[.,]` with `[,.](?!\d)` or `[,.](?!(?<=\d[,.])\d)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to handle this in passes:

- apply the splitting by punctuation
- apply the splitting by conjunctions

This would work in both of the test cases you provided